# Product delete index not working in Hybris Solr

Tags: solr, e-commerce, product, sap-commerce-cloud

I have one job and I linked it to a cronjob.
The error I get when I run my job's query and cronjob is available below.
As soon as I run the cronjob, it goes into Aborted - Error status.

Thank you very much in advance.

**Hybris version :**
2105.21

**Total Product :**
1121500 items

**Job Query :**
SELECT {p:PK} FROM {Product AS p},{ArticleApprovalStatus as ap} WHERE {p.approvalStatus}={ap.pk} and {ap.code} not in ('approved')

**ERROR LOG :**
2023-04-06 07:31:02.762 ERROR (qtp1493988307-28) [c:master_Product_flop s:shard1 r:core_node5 x:master_Product_flop_shard1_replica_n2] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'pk:(8798097276929 OR 8798097309697 OR 8798097342465 OR 8798097473537 OR 8798097604609 OR 8798097637377 OR 8798097670145 OR 8798097702913 OR 8798097735681 OR 8798097833985 OR 8798097866753 OR 8798097899521 OR 8798097932289 OR 8798097997825 OR 8798098030593 OR 8798098096129 OR 8798098128897 OR 8798098161665 OR 8798098194433 OR 8798098227201 OR 8798098259969 OR 8798098292737 OR 8798098325505 OR 8798098358273 OR 8798098391041 OR 8798098423809 OR 8798098456577 OR 8798098489345 OR 8798098522113 OR 8798098554881 OR 8798098587649 OR 8798098620417 OR 8798098718721 OR 8798098784257 OR 8798098849793 OR 8798098882561 OR 8798099013633 OR 8798099046401 OR 8798099079169 OR 8798099144705 OR 8798099177473 OR 8798099210241 OR 8798099275777 OR 8798099341313 OR 8798099406849 OR 8798099439617 OR 8798099505153 OR  ...........

Comment: which cronjob are you running ,as per jobs it looks like solr index--->if yes is there any specific requirement are you indexing not approved products.

Comment: @RaushanKumar The title says this is for Product Delete indexing

Comment: Can you post the entire error log? Is there at the end a description of the reason why it could not parse?

Comment: @RicardoMachado nothing else, that's the error that comes up with an error.